# iOS4: DateFormatter return NULL

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I have a String which has the following format: 2011-08-19T00:00:00 and I want now to change it in the following date format: August 19, 2011

I used the NSDateFormater this way:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:shiftNote.startDate];
```

But without success, date is always null.

Wheres the failure?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `[formatter setDateFormat:@"%B %d, %Y"];`, that means you must have a date *already* in this format. Since "2011-08-19T00:00:00" is not in this format, you'll have to convert it to a date *first*, then back to a string.